# Comparing Metadata in two resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two result sets

```
source rs;
target rs1;
```

I am storing metadata of a table in both the result set using below

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd=con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs=dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
```

table is having meta data as below.

```
name varchar 10;
age int 2;
salary double;
```

Please can anyone help me in this. I need to compare if both tables are having same column name and data type along with column length.

please also suggest if there is any better method.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare `DatabaseMetaData` and not `ResultSetMetaData`?

Comment: can you please suggest how i can do it with resultsetmetadata ? @daniu

Comment: Your question is unclear. Exactly what are you trying to do, what did you try, and exactly what are you stuck on.